# Validation does not work for REST requests

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to make it so that if the name is empty, then a certain text response will be discarded that the employee cannot be saved. I specifically did not specify not null in the database, because I want to prohibit adding an empty value in the application
Model code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worker")
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull(message = "Not null save")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public Worker(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Worker() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

my controller code:

```
 @PostMapping("/workers")
    public String create(@RequestBody @Valid Worker worker, Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return "No save";
        }
        workerService.create(worker);
        return "saved";
    }
```

my service code:

```
public void create(Worker worker) {
        workerRepository.save(worker);
    }
```

But when I try to forward a request without the name field or make it empty, it is still saved. It's like validation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to use `@NotBlank(message = "...")` instead of `@NotNull(message = "...")`. Presumably the REST API provides an empty string, not a `null` value. In case of doubt, I suggest you add a breakpoint to the controller method, run in debug mode and check what the variable content actually is.

Answer (score 0):

As Lobologic said empty string is not the same as null so that is the reason why a lot of people combine multiple annotations for validation something like

```
@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull(message = "Not null save")
@Size(min=1, message="is required")
private String name;
```

`@NotEmpty` and `@NotBlank` are also good checks but it depends on what you are trying to prevent and what you are trying to enforce as inputs.